# SecureConnectionLevel to 1 in RSReportDesigner configuration file using powershell script

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

How to set the value of SecureConnectionLevel to 1 in RSReportDesigner configuration file using powershell script?

The SecureConnectionLevel value is by default 0 , need to change to 1